# Spring Cloud Contract and Gradle Setup Question

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying out Spring Cloud Contract but cannot get it to run properly.
I have followed a couple of tutorials and looked into the spring-provided repository. The outcome is always the same:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.wolf.dependencies.BaseTest;
                            ^
  symbol:   class BaseTest
  location: package com.wolf.dependencies
```

This is how my build.gradle looks:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id "org.springframework.cloud.contract" version "3.1.5"
}

group = 'at.wolf'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudContractVersion', "3.1.5")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-dependencies:${springCloudContractVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

contracts {
    baseClassForTests = 'com.wolf.dependencies.BaseTest'
}
```

And the BaseTest class:

```
package at.wolf.dependencies;

import at.wolf.dependencies.controller.CustomerController;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.boot.AutoConfigureMessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
class BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerController customerController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        StandaloneMockMvcBuilder standaloneMockMvcBuilder
                = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerController);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(standaloneMockMvcBuilder);
    }

}
```

I suspect I have some mistake in my BaseTest class, but I'm not familiar enough with spring boot tests to determine what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, was a careless oversight. My base class is located in at.* and i set it as com.*